# Windows Phone open another application

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I need to **open a new application** from my application.  If it is not installed on the phone then I need to open the installation inside windows store.

Anybody have an idea how can I achieve this?

I read the below articles but I couldn't find anything helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207014%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

**Answer:**

For the store i ended up using:

```
private async void test()
    {
        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("zune://navigate/?appid=xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx");
            await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //TODO
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937(v=vs.105).aspx
describes how you can launch the store app and display a specific app

What you need will look something like this:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("zune:navigate?appid=[app ID]"));
```

where '[app ID]' needs to be replaced by the unique app id of the application you want to install.

Comment: how can i find the app id ? zune:navigate is to launch the store, any idea how to run the app if it is installed already

Comment: i got the id from the store on the web and i tried the above code but it didn't work i got an error "this content isn't available"

Comment: You can get the AppId by searching for an app in the store and looking at the last part of the apps detail page URL (a GUID). E.g. for the Url http://www.windowsphone.com/de-de/store/app/bing-sports/0f4c8c7e-7114-4e1e-a84c-50664db13b17 calling LaunchUriAsync with new Uri('zune:navigate?appid=0f4c8c7e-7114-4e1e-a84c-50664db13b17') will open the store page with 'Bing Sports' selected.