# On Windows Phone, how to launch another application

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8

On Windows Phone, some applications can be launch via an URI like "fb:" or "public-transit:".

How to launch an application when we know only the App Id like cded826e-f57d-4356-933c-4e59c1988157 (and not an eventual protocol) ?

I've tried, with the launchUriAsync function, "cded826e-f57d-4356-933c-4e59c1988157", "cded826e-f57d-4356-933c-4e59c1988157:", "{cded826e-f57d-4356-933c-4e59c1988157}" etc...

Thanks

Comment: You can't. WP doesn't allow this except through the URI as you wrote in your post.

Answer (score 1):

I could launch some apps via an URI.
List them as below.

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("whatsapp:"));
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("skype:"));
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("fbmessenger:"));
```

I just figured these out by try and error.
So maybe you could try to use app name to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

I only found a way to launch the app page in the store: calling LaunchUriAsync with new Uri('zune:navigate?appid=0f4c8c7e-7114-4e1e-a84c-50664db13b17') from this site [Windows Phone open another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246996/windows-phone-open-another-application)

Comment: Hélas, no.
It only launches the Windows Phone Store and shows the details page for the specified app...

Comment: this site maybe help you: [Auto-Launching apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) I will also look at it, because I also search how I can launch another app.